# Data scraper: the contents of the div tag is empty (??)

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am data scraping a website to get a number. This number changes dynamically every split second, but upon inspection, the number is shown. I just need to capture that number but the div wrapper that contains it, it returns no value. What am I missing? (please go easy on me as I am quite new to Python and data scraping).

I have some code that works and returns the piece of html that supposedly contains the data I want, but no joy, the `div` wrapper returns no value.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


r = requests.get('https://deuda-publica-espana.com')

deuda = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
deuda = deuda.findAll('div', {'id': 'contador_PDEH'})

print(deuda)
```

I don't receive any errors, I am just getting `[<div class="contador_xl contador_verde" id="contador_PDEH"></div>]` with no value!

Comment: The number is generated by Javascript, you can probably try other solutions, e.g. `selenium`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it is easy with selenium. I suspect there is a js script running a counter supplying the number which is why you can't find it with your method (as mentioned in comments)

```
from selenium import webdriver

d = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\User\Documents\chromedriver.exe')
d.get('https://deuda-publica-espana.com/')
print(d.find_element_by_id('contador_PDEH').text)
d.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I thought but I was getting confused, because upon inspection the number was still showing so it kind of weirded me out! Just a couple of questions to add on your response please:

+ by using selenium I am forcing the code to open a chrome window, right? is it possible to do it 'headless', in the background? can this be run in a raspberry pi with raspbian and chromium?

+ for future reference, is there any way to know when java is involved like in this case? that'd save me some huge headache! 

thanks in any case!

Comment: Sorry I hadn't seen your response. +Yes you can run it headless. +Your browser should offer you an option to turn of javascript (I created a profile for this with Chrome) - then load the page and see what content is present/ or use something like jquery/postman.... that can make xhr requests and inspect the return.